# Getting resolution of multiple images at the same time

Tags: shell

I am trying to loop through a directory of images and trying to get the resolution of multiple images at the same time and display them. How can I do this?

my images are in .jpeg and .png format. The names have '_' character like Transverse_H4096_W4096.jpeg and thumb.png

Comment: Are all the images the same format? What are the names like? Can the names contain spaces? Newlines? Other strange characters? What tool do you use to the resolution? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: my images are in .jpeg and .png format. The names have '_' character like Transverse_H4096_W4096.jpeg .

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** your question and add this information. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning.

Answer (score 3):

Using ImageMagick's `identify` to get the resolution of all JPG files in the current directory:

```
for image in *.jpg *.jpeg *.png
do
   echo "$image :"
   identify -format "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]\n" "$image"
done
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But my folder is a combination of both jpeg as well as png files. How can I get information of all kinds of image extensions at the same time.

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: @MaradaniLavanya see, that's why you need to explain all this in your question.

Comment: I am sorry for that. And thank you . It works

Comment: If this solution worked for you, please consider accepting this answer so other readers can find it more easily.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `exiftool` to get images metadata.

To install the tool on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

On Arch Linux:

```
sudo pacman -Sy perl-image-exiftool
```

Where `-S` is to syncronize packages (packages are installed directly from the remote repositories, including all dependencies required) and `-y` is to download a fresh copy of the master package database from the server(s) defined in `pacman.conf(5)` (from `man pacman`) .

Then to extract the needed data:

```
for image in ./images/*
do
   exiftool "-*FileName*" "-*ImageSize*" "$image"
done
```

The output will be:

```
File Name                       : linux.jpg
Image Size                      : 1920x1080
File Name                       : background.jpg
Image Size                      : 1020x980
```